# "svg:hover path" is only working on the last svg

Tags: html, css, svg, hover, responsive

I'm trying to have a responsive logo, that on hover the colour changes.

There are three versions of the logo which pop in and out with media queries, all that need the same effect, but only the last svg works

HTML:

```
<section class="welcome">

        <span id="slide">

            <svg id="RH1" data-name="RH1" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xml:space="preserve" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 840 158.3">...</svg>

            <svg id="RH2" data-name="RH2" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xml:space="preserve" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 595.2 143">...</svg>

            <svg id="RH3" data-name="RH3" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xml:space="preserve" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 200 143.9">...</svg>

        </span>

</section>
```

CSS:

```
svg {
    width:600px;
    height:115px;
    position:fixed;
    top:calc(50% - 50px);
    left:50%;
    margin-top:-56.5px;
    margin-left:-300px;
    cursor:pointer;
    fill:#3c9fd9;
}

svg:hover path {
    fill:#fff !important;
}

#RH2, #RH3 {opacity:0;}

@media only screen and (max-width:1100px) {#RH1, #RH3 {opacity:0;}#RH2 {opacity:1;}}
@media only screen and (max-width:570px) {#RH1, #RH2 {opacity:0;}#RH3 {opacity:1;}}
```

- https://codepen.io/robhalford92/pen/BLRQdd

thank you in advance!

Comment: _“but only the last svg works”_ – that’s because you placed them all on top of each other in the same position - so naturally your mouse cursor only “touches” the top one. If you want this to work, then you can’t just change the opacity of the “other” ones, you need to place them lower on the z-axis as well.

Comment: Doh! Thank you CBroe, I knew it had to be something simple. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you will find a [working pen as well](https://codepen.io/illdapt/pen/XjRpJJ).

Instead of using `opacity` to "hide" the others, try `display: none` on the elements you want to hide, thus allowing the logo you want to always be present hoverable and on top.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks Illdapt! - Just out of curiosity, why would having the extra media query make any difference? Would it not just fall back to the default css code?

Comment: Honestly, I couldn't tell you what was going on, however I overlooked you had `#RH2, #RH3 {opacity:0;}` and when changed to `#RH2, #RH3 {display:none;}` there too, it worked, Pen updated, thanks for the check!